# PDO: как вернуть строку запроса?

Tags: pdo, php_pdo, php

День добрый!

```
   $query_str ="SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_id = :id";
   $result = $this->prepare($query_str);
   $result->bindParam(':id',1234 );
   $result->execute();
```

Как получить строку `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_id = 1234`, средствами `PDO`

Comment: никак этого не сделать средствами PDO.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, такие вещи уходят (... и приходят :) ) SQL-серверу не в виде модифицированной строки, а в виде исходной строки и бинарного представления параметров. Следовательно - очень вряд ли такое возможно

Comment: если очень очень надо, то можно лог на mysql сервере включить и отловить запрос. (я точно не помню, но как вариант slow log можно очень маленьким сделать)

Answer (score 3):

Так? Подробности в ответе [rodneyrehm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515124/rodneyrehm) на [одном сайте](https://stackoverflow.com/) в вопросе [Get Last Executed Query in PHP PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716785/get-last-executed-query-in-php-pdo)

```
class MyPDOStatement extends PDOStatement
{
  protected $_debugValues = null;

  protected function __construct()
  {
    // этот пустой конструктор необходим
  }

  public function execute($values=array())
  {
    $this->_debugValues = $values;
    try {
      $t = parent::execute($values);
      // *размышления о логировании*
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      // *размышления о логировании*
      throw $e;
    }

    return $t;
  }

  public function _debugQuery($replaced=true)
  {
    $q = $this->queryString;

    if (!$replaced) {
      return $q;
    }

    return preg_replace_callback('/:([0-9a-z_]+)/i', array($this, '_debugReplace'), $q);
  }

  protected function _debugReplace($m)
  {
    $v = $this->_debugValues[$m[1]];
    if ($v === null) {
      return "NULL";
    }
    if (!is_numeric($v)) {
      $v = str_replace("'", "''", $v);
    }

    return "'". $v ."'";
  }
}

// см. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php
$options = array(
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
  PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS => array('MyPDOStatement', array()),
);

// создание PDO со своим PDOStatement классом
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

// подготовка запроса
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3)
  VALUES (:col1, :col2, :col3)");

// выполнение подготовленного выражения
$query->execute(array(
  'col1' => "hello world",
  'col2' => 47.11,
  'col3' => null,
));

// вывод запроса и запроса с подставленными данными
var_dump( $query->queryString, $query->_debugQuery() );
```

Доп. инфа: [замена параметров](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#98804), [зачем переопределять конструктор](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php#73568)

Comment: Это же не PDO. Если использовать вопросительный знак для обозначения переменных в запросе работать эта конструкция не будет. Также тут нет такой штуки как борьба с mysql injections. Реальный запрос остается за кулисами. Обманка короче. Но оформлена красиво, ничего не скажешь.

Comment: @zhenyab, почему это не PDO? Вполне себе.

Если использовать неименованные параметры, то запрос отработает, а вот ``_debugQuery()`` не подставит значения. Но пусть автору будет над чем подумать. Подумать можно еще и над ``bindParam()``.

Борьба с инъекциями какая была, такая и осталась, т.к. дергается родительский метод. Нет защиты только в ответе том самом ``_debugQuery()``, но я надеюсь, что автор не будет пытаться его потом выполнять :)

Согласен, что это не совсем реальный запрос. Более того, я и смысла особого в этом не вижу.